# Find an Inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I need to find the inverse of those functions:

1. $x \mapsto \sin e^{x}$
2. $x \mapsto e^{\sin x}$

I know that the way is to solve the equation $y = f(x)$ for $x$, and I did it with functions like ($x \mapsto x^2$, $2x+3$) but I can't do it with those too. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Neither of these functions is one-to-one, so the best you'll be able to do is find the inverse on a restriction of the domain. Has such a restriction been specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a function that when composed yields the identity, so $(f\circ f^{-1})(x)=(f^{-1}\circ f)=x$.  In this case we have composed function or $f\circ g$, what is the inverse?  It is $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.

For problem 1 $f(x)=\sin(x)$, $g(x)=e^x$, now what are the inverses of these functions?

For $\sin(x)$ we have $\arcsin(x)$ and for the exponential function the inverse is the natural logarithm ln($x$).

Composing the inverses we then get $(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})(x)$=ln($\arcsin(x)$).

Double check to convince yourself that this is correct and then attempt problem 2 using the same logic.

Comment: Thanks! I used the same logic for the second function and it worked perfect.